# How to debug Samsung S3 Gear through WIFI or any other way

Tags: android, adb, samsung-galaxy-gear

[image]In Gear S3  I have enabled 
**Debugging option.**
Wifi connected.
Wifi IP is 192.168.1.155

While giving the command   **adb connect 192.168.1.155** the below error is showing.

*C:\Users\mypcPc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools> adb connect 192.168.1.155:5556
unable to connect to 192.168.1.155:5556: cannot connect to 192.168.1.105:5556: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)*

Pls share if you have any ideas about this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: its in same wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think Problem is that your Device and System connected different
>   wifi.
>
> Connect your system and and Device with same Network...then try **adb
>   connect 192.168.1.155(replace your ip)**

Here is doc http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/testing-your-app-on-gear

Comment: Check here how to enable developer opitoin  https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-get-developer-options-on-android/

Comment: its a Samsung Gear, yes I have enabled developer option in the Gear watch

Comment: **adb devices** use this comment to get list of devices connect same network...check whether your devices is showing or not

Comment: @Ajitsree double check once your device and system connected same network or not????

Comment: @Ajitsree what OS you are using

Comment: @ Gowthaman M Yes its in same network, I have taken picture of the same and uploaded, pls view. I am using windows 10

Comment: @ Gowthaman M yes the Debugging options are enabled in the watch

Comment: @Ajitsree Follow the doc any problem let me know bro http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/testing-your-app-on-gear

Answer (score 3):

The Samsung Galaxy watches [run on the Tizen OS and are not meant to be connected to Android Studio via adb](https://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-for-galaxy-watch-over-adb-or-android-studio/201/356319?boardName=SDK&startId=00jPP~&startPage=8&curPage=10). In order to develop apps for these devices, you will need to use [Tizen Studio](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download) and connect to your device via sdb.